# Change Alt Attributes 1 time for 4 websites

Tags: magento-1.5

I'm working for the company Alterego_Design.

For the SEO, I Have to complete all ALT attributes of each product (we have +- 900 products)

But, we have 4 websites regrouped in Magento, and I have to make the work 4 times... With the loading of MAgento, it makes me a very long time to complet even 1 article...

Can you help me please ?

Here is a picture :

[image]

And when I complet the Alt attributes in "Valeur par défaut" >"Default Value", it doesn't work, so I have to complete theses ALT in each storeview !

Have you a solution to do that faster ?

Thanks